# Using XTickLabel in plotting

Tags: matlab

I am implementing a Matlab script in which I would like to plot a function as follows:

```
figure;
plot(Flows(:,1),Flows(:,2));
title(strcat('f',num2str(j),'\_2013\_0',num2str(k)));
xlabel('Timestamp');
ylabel('Energy flow');
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', datestr(Flows(:,1)));
```

Flows is a matrix which takes as input a csv file where the first column is a Timestamp value. There are 12 files, each one for every month. In a loop, I read the files and create the matrix.

```
Flows(i,1)=datenum(Input{i,1}{1,1},'YYYY-mm-DD HH:MM:SS');
Flows(i,2)=Input{i,1}{1,7};
```

However, when I plot the trend the x axis only shows date from 1st of January 00:00 until 1st of January 00:36. How could I display in the x axis, at least, from 1s of "Month" until the end of the month? I suspect the problem comes from the mask of the translation of the data from num to date, but I have tried several masks, which one is the suitable?

Comment: I suspect that you have to adjust 'xticks' as well (to show xticks at the resolution that you want to label). See example in here http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92565; Can you supply your data?

Comment: @Cici That's right. Not matching the `XTick`s with the `XTickLabel`s is also common pitfall [when creating `bar` plots](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20439903/2778484) since MATLAB doesn't automatically create the ticks when you go past a certain number of points.

Comment: @Jose Hdez, what version of Matlab are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've added these lines:

```
set(gca,'XLim',[min(Flows(:,1)) max(Flows(:,1))]);
set(gca,'XTick',Flows(:,1));
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', datestr(Flows(:,1)));
```

But, when I'm going to plot the trend, I get the following Exception,

```
Values must be monotonically increasing
```